# What's WQVGA for screen size?

Tags: vga

QVGA is 240 x 320, then WQVGA is 240 x 400, or 240+ x 400?

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_display_resolutions#WQVGA_.28240p.29):

> Wide QVGA or WQVGA is any display resolution having the same height in pixels as QVGA, but wider. This definition is consistent with other 'wide' versions of computer displays.

...

> WQVGA resolutions are common used in touch screen mobile phones, such as 240×400, 240×432, and 240×480. Other devices like Apple iPod nano uses a WQVGA screen, 240x376 pixels.

(There are more details on the wikipedia page.)

Comment: For 240x400, 240 is height? or 400?

Answer (score 0):

240, but:

> WQVGA has also been used to describe displays that are not 240 pixels
>   high, for example Sixteenth HD1080 displays which are 480 pixels wide
>   and 270 or 272 pixels high. This may be due to WQVGA having the
>   nearest screen height.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#WQVGA_.28400.C3.97240.29

So 240 (but also 270 or 272) width (or height in landscape mode) with heights of e.g. 360, 376, 384, 400, 428, 432, 480 pixels. (see [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#WQVGA_.28400.C3.97240.29).)